# Percentage calculation when extracting zip file going over 100%!

Tags: java, zip, progress

I'm extracting a zip file and the problem is that the percentage calculation goes over 100% and reaches almost to 111%.. Here is the code:

```
    boolean UNZipFiles() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    float prev = -1; // to check if the percent changed and its worth updating the UI
    int finalSize = 0;
    float current = 0;

    String zipFile = PATH + FileName;

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

    finalSize = (int) new File(zipFile).length();

    ZipEntry ze = null;

    while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        current += ze.getSize();

        if (ze.isDirectory())
            dirChecker(ze.getName());
        else {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(PATH + ze.getName());
            while ((length = zin.read(buffer)) > 0)
                fout.write(buffer, 0, length);

            if (prev != current / finalSize * 100) {
                prev = current / finalSize * 100;
                UpdatePercentNotificationBar((int) prev);
            }
            zin.closeEntry();
            fout.close();
        }

    }

    zin.close();

    return true;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Decompressing data takes a lot of CPU. What are you expecting to happen when you decompress files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finalSize = (int) new File(zipFile).length();` is the size of the compressed file, whereas `ze.getSize();` returns the size of the uncompressed data.

So your final % will be: (size of the uncompressed data) / (size of the zip file)

You would probably get a better result with `ze.getCompressedSize()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to count the bytes while reading the zip-file in order to calculate the percentage...

Answer (score 2):

```
finalSize = (int) new File(zipFile).length();
```

This doesn't give you the size of the expanded zip file, it gives you the size of the zip file itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `ZipEntry.getSize()` returns the uncompressed size of that entry. Try `ZipEntry.getCompressedSize()`.